# Simple Cluster algorithm 2D. Detecting clumps of points

Tags: c#, algorithm

Anyone know a simple algorithm to implement in C# to detect monster groups in a 2D game.

EX:
  100 Range around the char there are monsters.  I want to detect which monsters are within range 2 of each other, and if there is at-least 5 together, use the Area of Effect skill on that location. Otherwise use the single-target skill.

A link to an implementation would be great, C# preferably.  I just get lost reading the Wikipedia articles.

EDIT:
"your question is incomplete. what do you want to do exactly? do you want to find all groups? the biggest group? any group, if there are groups, none otherwise? please be more specific." -gilad hoch

I want to find all groups within 100 units of range around the main character.  The groups should be formed if there are at-least 5 or more monsters all within 2 range of each other, or maybe within 10 range from the center monster.

So the result should be probably a new List of groups or a List of potential target locations.

Comment: your question is incomplete. what do you want to do **exactly**? do you want to find _all_ groups? the _biggest_ group? _any_ group, if there are groups, none otherwise? please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently implemented the algorithm given in [this paper](http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http://www.cs.arizona.edu/~alon/papers/cir.ps.gz&ei=HghuULuhJ4yi8ASEi4HADg&usg=AFQjCNFoYRdkCoq4WSRBIxsw6UoeN1lg6A&sig2=XHyE5y9P2ZofvyLUg7ZkGQ) by Efraty, which solves the problem by considering the intersections of circles of radius 2 centered at each given point. In simple terms, if you order the points in which two circles intersect in clockwise order, then you can do something similar to a line sweep to figure out the point in which a bomb (or AoE spell) needs to be launched to hit the most enemies. The implementation is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

#define INF 1e16
#define eps 1e-8
#define MAXN 210
#define RADIUS 2

struct point {
    double x,y;

    point() {}
    point(double xx, double yy) : x(xx), y(yy) {}

    point operator*(double ot) {
        return point(x*ot, y*ot);
    }

    point operator+(point ot) {
        return point(x+ot.x, y+ot.y);
    }

    point operator-(point ot) {
        return point(x-ot.x, y-ot.y);
    }

    point operator/(double ot) {
        return point(x/ot, y/ot);
    }
};

struct inter {
    double x,y;
    bool entry;
    double comp;

    bool operator< (inter ot) const {
        return comp < ot.comp;
    }
};

double dist(point a, point b) {
    double dx = a.x-b.x;
    double dy = a.y-b.y;
    return sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
}

int N,K;
point p[MAXN];
inter it[2*MAXN];


struct distst {
    int id, dst;
    bool operator<(distst ot) const {return dst<ot.dst;}
};

distst dst[200][200];
point best_point;

double calc_depth(double r, int i) {
    int left_inter = 0;

    point left = p[i];
    left.y -= r;
    best_point = left;

    int tam = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        int j = dst[i][k].id;
        if (i==j) continue;

        double d = dist(p[i], p[j]);

        if (d > 2*r + eps) break;
        if (fabs(d)<eps) {
            left_inter++;
            continue;
        }

        bool is_left = dist(p[j], left) < r+eps;
        if (is_left) {
            left_inter++;
        }

        double a = (d*d) / (2*d);

        point diff = p[j] - p[i];
        point p2 = p[i] + (diff * a) / d;

        double h = sqrt(r*r - a*a);

        it[tam].x = p2.x + h*( p[j].y - p[i].y ) / d;
        it[tam].y = p2.y - h*( p[j].x - p[i].x ) / d;  

        it[tam+1].x = p2.x - h*( p[j].y - p[i].y ) / d;
        it[tam+1].y = p2.y + h*( p[j].x - p[i].x ) / d; 

        it[tam].x -= p[i].x;
        it[tam].y -= p[i].y;
        it[tam+1].x -= p[i].x;
        it[tam+1].y -= p[i].y;

        it[tam].comp = atan2(it[tam].x, it[tam].y);
        it[tam+1].comp = atan2(it[tam+1].x, it[tam+1].y);

        if (it[tam] < it[tam+1]) {
            it[tam].entry = true;
            it[tam+1].entry = false;
        }
        else {
            it[tam].entry = false;
            it[tam+1].entry = true;
        }

        if (is_left) {
            swap(it[tam].entry, it[tam+1].entry);
        }

        tam+=2;
    }

    int curr,best;
    curr = best = left_inter;

    sort(it,it+tam);

    for (int j = 0; j < tam; j++) {
        if (it[j].entry) curr++;
        else curr--;

        if (curr > best) {
            best = curr;
            best_point = point(it[j].x, it[j].y);
        }
    }

    return best;
}

int main() {
    scanf("%d", &N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        scanf("%lf %lf", &p[i].x, &p[i].y);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            dst[i][j].id = j;
            dst[i][j].dst = dist(p[i],p[j]);
        }
        sort(dst[i],dst[i]+N);
    }

    int best = 0;
    point target = p[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int depth = calc_depth(RADIUS, i);
        if (depth > best) {
            best = depth;
            target = best_point;
        }
    }

    printf("A bomb at (%lf, %lf) will hit %d target(s).\n", target.x, target.y, best+1);
}
```

Sample usage:

```
2 (number of points) 
0 0
3 0
A bomb at (1.500000, 1.322876) will hit 2 targets.
```

Answer (score 2):

a very simple clustering algorithm is the k-mean algorithm. it is like

- create random points
- assign all points to the nearest point, and create groups
- relocate the original points to the middle of the groups
- do the last two steps several times.

an implementation you can find for example here, or just google for "kmean c#"

http://kunuk.wordpress.com/2011/09/20/markerclusterer-with-c-example-and-html-canvas-part-3/