# Calculating Slots hit with AOE in a 4x3 Array

Tags: c#

I'm not exactly what terminology to even use to look this up, and I figure the best way to explain it is with an example image.

I have a game field made up of 12 (numbered 1-12) slots, 4 wide and 3 deep, I need to be able to take the main slot number hit and get the numbers of its neighboring slots for an Area of Effect system.

[image: Example Image: AoE on 4x3 array of Slots]

Comment: include relevant code..

Comment: Did you read the description of `[slots]` before you tagged your question with that tag.  It's some sort of Python feature

Comment: I don't think my code is relevant in this case. Let's just assume I generate a random number from 1-12 and it picks 6. How would I go about getting slot 6's neighboring slots as shown in the included image? Some fancy multidimensional array business I'm assuming.

Comment: Have you done any research? I searched for "area of effect" implementation and found [Simple Cluster algorithm 2D. Detecting clumps of points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12736395/215552), which sounds pretty close...

Comment: instead consider creating a slot class which has a row and column property to identify the slot position. all 12 slots will be stored in `slots` variable of type List<Slot>. Now, slot "6" is at row 1, column 1 (index starting at 0). then slots in the "Area of Effect" could be all slots in the list that are at (row -1, col), (row + 1, col), (row, col - 1), (row, col + 1), (row -1, col -1) (row + 1, col -1), (row - 1, col + 1) and (row + 1, col + 1)

Comment: Using X/Y coordinates is one good way I hadn't thought of for this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one sample implementation, but it may not work depending on how you're storing your data. The first part just creates the array, then the second part asks the user to select a number so we can highlight it and it's neighbors.

All we have to do is check if the current row is within `1` of the selected row, and if the current column is within `1` of the selected column, and hightlight that square (because it'a a neighbor). Of course if both the row and column match, then we highlight that a little differently since that's the number they chose:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var rowCount = 4;
    var colCount = 3;
    var slots = new int[rowCount, colCount];

    // Populate the grid
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount * colCount; i++)
    {
        var col = i / rowCount;
        var row = i % rowCount;

        slots[row, col] = i + 1;
    }

    // Print the grid
    for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < colCount; col++)
        {
            Console.Write($" {slots[row, col]}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    // Ask the user to select a number from the grid
    var chosenNumber = GetIntFromUser("\nSelect a number: ", 
        x => x > 0 && x < rowCount * colCount);

    // Get the coordinates of that selected number
    var selCol = (chosenNumber - 1) / 4;
    var selRow = (chosenNumber - 1) % 4;

    // Print the grid, highlighting their 
    // selected number and it's neighbors
    Console.WriteLine();
    for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < colCount; col++)
        {
            if (row == selRow && col == selCol)
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            }
            else if (row >= selRow - 1 && row <= selRow + 1 &&
                     col >= selCol - 1 && col <= selCol + 1)
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.ResetColor();
            }

            Console.Write($" {slots[row, col]}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image: ![![Sample output from above code]

Oh,and the helper function I used to get a valid number is:

```
private static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt, Func<int, bool> validator = null)
{
    int result;
    var cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;

    do
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cursorTop);
        Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cursorTop);
        Console.Write(prompt);

    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) ||
                !(validator?.Invoke(result) ?? true));

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This was very kind of you.  Only critique would be to use constants for your table sizes as right now it is very magical.